# How to change route from outside router component in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have created a route in React.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Header isLogged={this.state.isLoggedIn} userdata={this.props.userdata}/>
        <div className='container'>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => (<LoginPage handleLogIn={this.handleLogIn} alterLoginStatus={this.alterLoginStatus} {...props}/>)} />
            <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={DashboardPage}/>
              <Route path="/contact"  component={Contact}/>
              <Route component={PageNotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In my Header component I have a button in navbar, upon which click I want to clear some localstorage and navigate to **/login**.

```
this.props.history.push('/login') is not working as I dont have access to router props inside Header component.
```

Please help me.

Comment: you can use browserHistory like : 

``` browserHistory.push('/login') ```

and if you want to clear any localStorage then dispatch an action where you can clear localStorage and then navigate to /login route.

Comment: 'react-router-dom' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'. How to import browserHistory

Comment: import it from `react-router`

Comment: I a using react-router-dom. Should i import react-router

Comment: ` import {browserHistory} from 'react-router' `

logout() {
  localStorage.removeItem('key');
         this.props.logoutHard();
  browserHistory.push('/login');
 }

Comment: 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'. I am using react router-4